# Can't sort an #ask table in semantic mediawiki

Tags: semantic-mediawiki

This should be straightforward, but I just can't get it to work... I have a semantic mediawiki installation with a few pages with properties and an "#ask" which displays a table of those properties. I believe using "order=" on the #ask should specify the default display order for the table, but no matter what I do, they always display in creation order.

Example query:

```
{{#ask:
[[Category:Object]]
|?Prop
| format=table
| sort=Prop
| order=asc
}}
```

With 3 pages containing the following content:

```
[[Category:Object]]
[[Prop::11]]
```

```
[[Category:Object]]
[[Prop::33]]
```

```
[[Category:Object]]
[[Prop::22]]
```

But the table always displays with the `Prop` order of "11, 33, 22". The arrows reorder the table correctly, it's just the default order I can't influence.

Running "semantic mediawiki 4.1.0" with "Semantic Result Formats 4.0.1" on "MediaWiki   1.38.4".

I've compared with demos and even reinstalled semantic mediawiki, but nothing affects it. I've declared `Property:Prop` as `[[Has type::number]]`. Feels like it's something more fundamental than syntax.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you run the jobs after setting property type?

Comment: By "run the job" do you mean running the #ask query? Yes run that lots of time with all sorts of settings. I'm going to try running the maintenance script to rebuild the database in case that's an issue.

Comment: No, I mean running the job queue. Its the Runjob.php that is in the maintenance directory.

Comment: FYI this is still a problem but superceded by a more specific question as I found the test page is also missing an "order by" option:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77512104/how-to-enable-sort-of-tables-on-semantic-mediawiki

Answer (score 0):

Finally discovered the answer - I had variable `$smwgQSortFeatures` set to a duff value which had the side-effect of disabling all sort features. When I disabled the assignment, all search behaviour and GUI came back to life!!