# How to enable sort of tables on Semantic MediaWiki

Tags: semantic-mediawiki

The test page on the semantic mediawiki demo site has a "Sort options" box:
https://www.semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Special:Ask

[image: Sort on test page]

But my site with up-to-date semantic mediawiki installed does not:
http://wiki.andelainfilms.com/index.php/Special:Ask

[image: Sort on my site]

This is consistent with behaviour when adding sort properties to tables, nothing makes any influence on the order of results despite documentation to the contrary.

Am I missing an extension that makes this happen?

Comment: What is the value of `$smwgQSortFeatures`?

Answer (score 0):

Press [+] near "Parameters".

Comment: Nice try but no, it's not there - the 'sort options' is outside the 'parameters' in the first pic.